# Help, im new to C++ i need some advice

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Input a Sentence: ";
  cin >> x;
  {
  char* string = x;
  int letter_count[26];

  // Initialization
  for(int i=0; i<26; letter_count[i++]=0);

  // Counting the number of letters
  for(int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if(string[i] > 64 && string[i] < 91)
      letter_count[string[i]-65]++;
    else if (string[i] > 96 && string[i] < 123)
      letter_count[string[i]-97]++;

    else if (string[i] == '.')
      break;
  }

  // Show the result

  for(int i=0; i < 26; i++)
    if (letter_count[i] != 0)
      std::cout << letter_count[i] << " "<< char(i+97) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Why doesn't this program compile?

Comment: What is the question you wanted to ask?

Comment: You should definitely include the actual error messages from the compiler; chances are they explain the problem (and solution!) specifically.

Comment: Which compiler are you using (eg.. VS 2008 , g++ etc)

Answer (score 3):

- Your code won't be able to compile. You used `x` in `cin << x` before declaring it.
- use `std::getline` to read a line.
- Don't use std type name (string) as the variable name. (Thanks to bdonlan)
- Don't use magical number (63,etc).

  By combine above together, we have this. This is far from perfect , but it is improved.

  ```
      cout << "Input a Sentence: ";
      string line;
      std::getline(std::cin , line);

  int letter_count[26];

  // Initialization
  for(int i= 0; i<26; i++)
  {
      letter_count[i] = 0;
  }

  // Counting the number of letters
  for(int i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      if(line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'z'){
              letter_count[line[i]-'a']++;
      }else if (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z'){
              letter_count[line[i]-'A']++;
      }else if (line[i] == '.')
              break;
  }

  // Show the result
  ```

Comment: `string` isn't a keyword - but it's a type in this context because of the `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you have to declare `x` before you can use it.

Also you can change

```
 int letter_count[26];

  // Initialization
  for(int i=0; i<26; letter_count[i++]=0);
```

to just

```
int letter_count[26] = {0};
```

Comment: `return 0` at the and of `main`? If you mean it as a good habit, then maybe... Maybe. Otherwize, `main` automatically returns `0` at completion, even without an explicit `return 0` statement. `main` is special in that regard.

Comment: I suppose you're right that it's unnecessary in `main`, I just wanted him to learn that he should return from his functions.

Answer (score 1):

don't use the word string as your variable name, you are including the string.h header which defines a class with the same name,

and yes,it would be better if you write a question with a specific problem

Comment: how do i defined x in the scope?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have declared the `x` variable. It should be a `std::string`:

```
string x;
```

After reading the input you declare a variable called `string` (with `char* string = x;`). If you leave out that line and just use `x` everywhere where you now use `string` your program compiles fine.

It also already very nearly does what I guess you intend it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem in your code is that you didn't declare the variable `x` before use. (And your declaration was weird. To declare a variable, put the type followed by the name, like `char* x`, optionally followed by an assignment to initialize it, `char* x = "hello world"`. After the variable has been declared, the compiler will let you use it.

```
#include <iostream> // include the header containing cout and cin
#include <string> // include the header containing the string class
// using namespace std; // don't do this. Prefix standard library names with the std namespace instead

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Input a Sentence: ";
  std::string x; // declare a variable named x, so we can use it afterwards - and use the C++ string class, not char*
  //std::cin >> x; // only reads a word into x. If we want a sentence, use getline instead:
  std::getline(cin, x);
  int letter_count[26] = {}; // automatically fills the array with zeros

  // Counting the number of letters
  for(std::string::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it) { // might as well use iterators. That's what they're for. And then your code behaves better if the string actually contains a \0 character.
    if(*it >= 'A' && *it <= 'Z'){ // never leave out the {}'s. It'll blow up on you later, when you modify the code
      letter_count[*it - 'A']++;
    }
    else if (*it >= 'a' && *it <= 'z'){
      letter_count[*it-'a']++;
    }
    else if (*it == '.'){
      break;
    }
  }

  // Show the result

  for(int i=0; i < 26; i++)
    if (letter_count[i] != 0)
      std::cout << letter_count[i] << " "<< static_cast<char>(i+97) << std::endl; // prefer C++-style casts
  }
}
```